# Пунктуация. Оформление девизов, включенных в предложение, и т.д

Tags: пунктуация

1) Вот такой вопрос: как оформляются девизы, лозунги, включенные в предложение, и предложения такого типа: 
На вопрос " Как провел лето?" он ответил: "Хорошо!" Или после "на вопрос" ставится двоеточие?
На вопрос: "Как он провел лето?" он ответил: "Хорошо". Нигде не нашла. Помогите разобраться, заранее благодарю!
2) Почему в одних случаях, например, слово "случайно" пишется раздельно с "не", а в других - слитно. Меня интересует вот это правило: 
Пишется слитно, если предложение несет утверждение, и пишется раздельно, если несет отрицание.

Рабочий неслучайно награжден орденом Труда. (Утверждается закономерность).

Рабочий не случайно награжден орденом Труда. (Отрицается случайность).

Ведь если посмотреть, то в обоих этих предложениях слово "случайно" можно заменить синонимом без "не". А как известно, если слово заменяется синонимом без "не", то тогда оно пишется с частицей слитно. Или я что-то здесь не поняла? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Alena, У Вас тут два несвязанных вопроса. Так оформите каждый как отдельный вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вопросы, построенные таким способом, мне попались в одной книге. Но иногда в книгах попадаются опечатки. Вот поэтому мне и стало интересно, как оформляется, потому что подобной пунктуации я ещё не встречала, даже в справочнике Д.Розенталя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно двоякое оформление. Если следовать правилу по оформлению прямой речью, то двоеточие ставится.

*На вопрос: " Как провел лето?" — он ответил: "Хорошо!"*

Но в справочнике Д.Э. Розенталя дается такая рекомендация: "подлинные выражения, вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, заключаются в кавычки, но двоеточие перед ними не ставится. То же сказано и в полном академическом справочнике «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации»:

> Если прямая речь непосредственно включается в авторское предложение в
> качестве его члена, то она заключается в кавычки, знаки же препинания
> ставятся по условиям авторского предложения: **Сказав Гричмару фразу
> «Легкой жизни не бывает, есть лишь легкая смерть», Крымов поймал на
> себе беспокойный, предупреждающий взгляд Стишова (Бонд.).**

Следуя этим рекомендациям, ваше предложение можно оформить и без двоеточия.

*На вопрос "Как провел лето?" — он ответил: "Хорошо!"*

Что касается слитного/раздельного написания "не (случайно), то здесь действует правило правописания **НЕ** с краткими прилагательными. Вот рекомендация  полного академического справочника «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации»:

> *Пишущий должен отдавать себе отчет в том, что он хочет выразить: отрицание признака — и тогда написать НЕ отдельно от следующего слова*
> (напр.: он не здоров, не важно, не редки случаи, **не случайно,** не
> существенно, не удивительно, не демократическим путём) или утверждение
> признака — и тогда написать НЕ слитно (ср.: он нездоров, нередки
> случаи, неважно, **неслучайно**, несущественно, неудивительно,
> недемократическим путем). От выбора написания будет зависеть и
> понимание написанного читающими **(Правила русской орфографии и
> пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина.
> М., 2006. § 149).**

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Очень помогли.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, пишущий должен отдавать себе отчет в том, что он хочет выразить: отрицание признака или утверждение.  **Но обычно он не отдает  себе в этом отчета, он просто не умеет этого делать.**

В Нацкорпусе частотность "не случайно" и "неслучайно" 4800:430, причем трудно определить какую-либо закономерность: практически в одинаковых случаях употребляются разные формы.

Дело в том, что смысл их одинаков, структуры предложений с отрицанием и утверждением также сходны. Ну вот что делать с этим рабочим?

**Можно предположить следующее.**

**1) Если пишем раздельно,** то доказательство факта неслучайности следуют потом, например: **Рабочий не случайно награжден орденом Труда:  его многолетний труд  отмечен наивысшими показателями производительности труда и  качества продукции.** Здесь действует формула противопоставления: **не случайно, а закономерно.**

**2) Если пишем слитно,** то достижения указываем вначале: **Передовик производства, ветеран труда,  автор многих рационализаторских предложений, рабочий неслучайно награжден орденом Труда.** То есть передовик закономерно получил орден Труда.

Примечание: вернее сказать, Орден Трудового Красного Знамени.

Comment: Большое спасибо за объяснение!