# Скажите, пожалуйста, "не обязательно" в моем предложение (смотрите ниже) НЕ должно писаться слитно или отдельно? Спасибо!

Tags: орфография

Предисловие:
Моей подруге Л. посвящается (остальным читать не обязательно. Но если Вы прочитаете, то прежде, чем критиковать «подарок» со словами «Это ж, элементарно, Ватсон!», подумайте. Его Вам могли не подарить, а продать за 1000 (€ или консультаций) у дорогих коучей и психологов. Хотя последние однозначно стоят Ваших вложений. Ибо часто реальность такова: мы ценим и используем гораздо больше то, что нам за-дорого-€€€€-придорого-продали, чем то, что нам просто подарили. ;)

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433617/%d0%9f%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9e%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d1%82-%d0%b4

Answer (score 0):

*Ответ на ваш вопрос - слитно. Но, чтобы разобраться в ситуации и понимать, как в дальнейшем писать правильно, ниже нашел для вас пояснение темы:*

Согласно орфографической норме русского языка оба варианта являются правильными. Давайте разберем в каком случае нужно писать первый вариант, а в каком – второй.

**Когда пишем слитно?**

Отметим, что слово “необязательно” является наречием.

В данном случае мы руководствуемся следующим правилом:

*“С наречиями, оканчивающимися на “-о/-е”, “не” пишется слитно, если наречие можно заменить синонимом без “не”.*

Отметим, что в предложении при определённых условиях “не обязательно” пишется и раздельно.

**Когда пишем раздельно?**

Мы пишем наречие “не обязательно” раздельно:

если в предложении имеется противопоставление с союзом “а”.
**Например:** не обязательно, а свободно добровольно (где “свободно добровольно” – это противопоставление).

если перед наречием имеются следующие конструкции: далеко не, отнюдь не, вовсе не.
**Например:** вовсе не обязательно, отнюдь не обязательно.

если перед наречием имеется другое наречие, начинающееся с “ни”.
Например: нисколько не обязательно.

[Источник](https://russkiypro.ru/pravilnoe-pravopisanie-neobyazatelno-ili-ne-obyazatelno/)